# Trying to create simple application using HERE SDK

Tags: android, here-api

We're trying to build a simple application with the HERE SDK. We are following the instructions on the following link: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html .
However, in step 1 of **Add HERE SDK Libraries to Your Project** we cannot find the HERE jar files that should be added to the project.
How can we download the HERE library files?

Answer (score 0):

Download the 90 days evaluation version here, this includes all files and docs you need: https://developer.here.com/plans/mobile-sdk

Comment: HERE site is little confusing. It should be able to download the SDK generally, not per app.

Comment: The SDK is not bound to an app, but the license key you need to use it is (bound to the app namespace).